# Is there any way to execute image processing functions (such as image transforms, feature matching, etc) using raspberry?

Tags: image, image-processing, raspberry-pi, feature-detection

I am willing to know that is it possible to execute image processing useful techniques such as image transforms, feature extraction, feature matching, etc by raspberry pi? I mean, is this processor powerful enough to perform such computations?

Comment: Yes, you can use OpenCV

Comment: This may help https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/robot/blob_detection/